# Select DISTINCT on a particular field

Tags: 8, database

I want to return distinct values based on a particular column - 'company_code'. How do I achieve this? My code is as below.

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('actuarial_bases', 'bases')
                    ->fields('bases', ['company_code','basis_id','mortality','commission','initial_expenses','recurring_expenses','date_saved','discount_rate'])
                    ->condition('approved_by',!"")
                    ->orderBy('date_saved', 'DESC')
                    ->distinct();
```

Comment: That's not what `DISTINCT` is for - for example, `SELECT DISTINCT foo, bar ...` will select unique values based on a combination of all fields, not just the first one, or a particular one (by design). `GROUP BY` is the one you're looking for

Comment: Maybe you could try to use $query->groupBy('bases.company_code')

Comment: 'Group By' didn't work for me.

Comment: `condition('approved_by',!"")` isn't selecting the rows for which *approved_by* isn't empty. Probably that's the reason why it doesn't work. A question about code should show the exact code used by the module, without any syntax error. The question should also explain why the code doesn't work and in which way the result is different from what expected.

Answer (score 0):

Searching, I found [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql).

I created a view to include 'row_count' using the following query.

```sql
SELECT `company_code`, `basis_id`, `mortality`, `commission`, `initial_expenses`, `recurring_expenses`, `discount_rate`, `date_saved`,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(0) FROM `actuarial_bases` `b` WHERE
      (
        (`a`.`date_saved` <= `b`.`date_saved`) AND ( `a`.`company_code` = `b`.`company_code`)
      )
  ) AS `row_number`
  FROM `actuarial_bases` `a`
```

I then used the following code do programmatically execute the query.

```php
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('bases_in_force', 'b')
  ->fields('b', ['company_code','basis_id','mortality','commission','initial_expenses','recurring_expenses','date_saved','discount_rate'])
  ->condition('row_number',1)
  ->orderBy('date_saved', 'DESC');
$results = $query->execute();
```